# Pyparsing indents and de-indents

Tags: python, regex, pyparsing

I am parsing a configuration file of router. Usually I am using regex with named groups and for this purpose:
https://regex101.com/r/EcyPeh/5
In this example I use 'svcindent' named group + keyword "exit" as de-indent of service configuration context.

How to make the same thing with pyparsing?

There is SkipTo(intend + Keyword("exit") in following source code. I am trying to use it as de-indent. But it match various number of white spaces. That is why it match the "exit" keyword of stp context.

```
from pyparsing import *

data = """
        vpls 82 customer 700 i-vpls create
            service-mtu 9040
            send-flush-on-failure
            propagate-mac-flush
            stp
                shutdown
            exit
            sap 2/2/8:0.1 create
                ingress
                    qos 13
                    queue-override
                        queue 1 create
                            cbs 1000
                            rate 10240 cir 10240
                        exit
                    exit
                exit
            exit
            spoke-sdp 4:82 endpoint "vpls-82-uplink" create
                stp
                    shutdown
                exit
                precedence primary
                no shutdown
            exit
            spoke-sdp 6:82 endpoint "vpls-82-uplink" create
                stp
                    shutdown
                exit
                no shutdown
            exit
            mac-move
                no shutdown
            exit
            no shutdown
        exit
        vpls 121 customer 700 i-vpls create
            service-mtu 9040
            send-flush-on-failure
            propagate-mac-flush
            stp
                shutdown
            exit
            sap 2/2/9:900 create
                ingress
                    qos 13
                    queue-override
                        queue 1 create
                            cbs 3000
                            rate 10240 cir 10240
                        exit
                    exit
                exit
            exit
            spoke-sdp 4:121 endpoint "vpls-121-uplink" create
                stp
                    shutdown
                exit
                precedence primary
                no shutdown
            exit
            spoke-sdp 6:121 endpoint "vpls-121-uplink" create
                stp
                    shutdown
                exit
                no shutdown
            exit
            mac-move
                no shutdown
            exit
            no shutdown
        exit
        vpls 1986692 customer 555 i-vpls create
            service-mtu 9040
            send-flush-on-failure
            propagate-mac-flush
            stp
                shutdown
            exit
            sap 2/2/9:130 create
                ingress
                    qos 13
                    queue-override
                        queue 1 create
                            cbs 1000
                            rate 10240 cir 10240
                        exit
                    exit
                exit
            exit
            spoke-sdp 4:1986692 endpoint "vpls-1986692-uplink" create
                stp
                    shutdown
                exit
                precedence primary
                no shutdown
            exit
            spoke-sdp 6:1986692 endpoint "vpls-1986692-uplink" create
                stp
                    shutdown
                exit
                no shutdown
            exit
            mac-move
                no shutdown
            exit
            no shutdown
        exit
"""
indent = LineStart() + OneOrMore(White(' ', exact=4))
deident = matchPreviousExpr(indent) + Keyword("exit")
svc_id = Word(nums)
customer_id = Word(nums)
sp = White(' ', exact=1)
svc_stmt = Combine(indent("int_s") + Keyword("vpls") + sp + svc_id + sp + Keyword("customer") + sp + customer_id + SkipTo(Keyword("create"), include=True)) + Combine(SkipTo(deident, include=True))

svc_stmt.leaveWhitespace()
parseTree = svc_stmt.searchString(data)
parseTree.pprint()



Result:
[['        vpls 82 customer 700 i-vpls create',
'\n'
'            service-mtu 9040\n'
'            send-flush-on-failure\n'
'            propagate-mac-flush\n'
'            stp\n'
'                shutdown\n'
'            exit'],
['        vpls 121 customer 700 i-vpls create',
'\n'
'            service-mtu 9040\n'
'            send-flush-on-failure\n'
'            propagate-mac-flush\n'
'            stp\n'
'                shutdown\n'
'            exit'],
['        vpls 1986692 customer 555 i-vpls create',
'\n'
'            service-mtu 9040\n'
'            send-flush-on-failure\n'
'            propagate-mac-flush\n'
'            stp\n'
'                shutdown\n'
'            exit']]
```

Comment: Pyparsing inherently skips whitespace, so whitespace-delimited text is something of a challenge. You are on the right track with the `matchPreviousExpr`, but when you go in a level, the previous expression has to change - then when you hit 'exit' it has to change back. So you'll need some kind of stack of indent levels. Also, you'll need to use Forward so that you have a mutable prior expression.

There is a method called `indentedBlock` that implements indented parsing. You can modify your code to use that, or use that code as a template for your own implementation.